# Basic Classification of Energy

Tags: energy, potential-energy, big-list

When I was still in school, I  learnt that there are 2 types of energy: Potential & Kinetic Energy. When I searched Wikipedia and other sources, there were many forms of energy. There are some sources pointing towards  Potential/Kinetic energy. But  they do not consist all forms of energy according to me.

Can anybody make a list/classification/ranking of Energy?

Example:

1. Potential Energy

   - form 1
   - form 2
   - form 3
   - . . .
2. Kinetic Energy

   - form 1
   - form 2
   - form 3
   - . . .
3. Type 3 (if any)

   - form 1
   - form 2
   - form 3
   - . . .

I hope my question is clear to all of you. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When I was still in school, I learnt that there are 2 types of energy: Potential & Kinetic Energy.

That's what people tend to say. But I'm afraid what you learn in school isn't always correct.

> When I searched Wikipedia and other sources, there were many forms of energy.

Yes, for example [this GCSE bitesize webpage](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/aqa_pre_2011/energy/heatrev4.shtml) refers to magnetic, kinetic, heat, light, gravitational potential, chemical, sound, electrical, elastic potential, and nuclear. I dislike this list for various reasons. For example electromagnetic unification means  electric energy and magnetic energy are two sides of the same coin. And like valerio92 said, chemical energy is potential energy and thermal energy is kinetic energy. See [this classification](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/formsofenergy-141207060656-conversion-gate01/95/forms-of-energy-9-638.jpg?cb=1422286565) of different forms of energy under the potential and kinetic headings:

[image]

> There are some sources pointing towards Potential/Kinetic energy. But they do not consist all forms of energy according to me. Can anybody make a list/classification/ranking of Energy?

It's tricky. You could talk about photon energy E=hf, which is light energy. But neutrino energy isn't. Nor is mass-energy, or gravitational field energy, or dark energy, and so on. And when all is said and done, energy is... energy. You can't define it in terms of something else. Nor can you define it as a property, like the colour red. It's a real thing. It's the one thing you can neither create nor destroy. It's fundamental. And matter is made of it. *You* are made of it. To appreciate this, look at [Compton scattering](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/comptint.html):

[image]<sub>Image courtesy of Rod Nave's [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/compton.html#c1)</sub>

In Compton scattering we convert some of the photon's E=hc/λ kinetic wave energy into electron kinetic energy. If we perform another Compton scatter using the residual photon, and another and another, then in the limit you remove all of the photon kinetic energy, and there's no wave left. The photon has then been entirely converted into electron kinetic energy. But in [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) you can convert the photon into an electron and a positron, so you can say the electron is quite literally *made* of kinetic energy.

Only it gets worse. Because when you throw the electron up in the air, you do work on it. You exert a force on it for a distance, you give it kinetic energy. You add energy to it. When the electron slows down and reaches its highest point, we call this extra energy gravitational potential energy. Then as the electron falls down, we say this potential energy is converted back into kinetic energy. But at all times the electron is *made of kinetic energy*. All that happens when you throw the electron up is that external kinetic energy is converted into internal kinetic energy. The opposite happens when it falls down. Then when you dissipate that external kinetic energy as radiation, you're left with a [mass deficit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass-energy_relation). So mass-energy *is* kinetic energy *is* potential energy. That's what [E=mc²](http://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/www/) is all about. But unfortunately they don't teach *that* in schools.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, as someone pointed out in the comments, potential/kinetic classification is the only meaningful classification in physics.

Potential energy is the energy which comes from *interaction*, and kinetic energy is the energy which comes from *motion*.

Maybe you stumbled upon terms like *chemical energy*, *thermal energy* and so on. But chemical energy is just the energy stored in chemical bonds between molecules, so ultimately it is just potential energy. And thermal energy comes from the molecular motion of the molecules in the system, so it is actually kinetic energy, and so on...